# MySQL WHERE seems to be failing?

Tags: mysql

Here is a query I have:

```
INSERT INTO Fixtures (`LeagueID`,`HomeID`,`AwayID`,`GameDate`,`GameWeek`)
                    SELECT
                            1,
                            `HomeTeam`.`Id`,
                            `AwayTeam`.`Id`,
                            '11/05/2014',
                            12
                    FROM
                            `Teams` HomeTeam,
                            `Teams` AwayTeam
                    WHERE
                            `HomeTeam`.`Id` = 'West Brom'
                            AND `AwayTeam`.`Id` = 'Stoke'
```

It takes two values, in this case 'West Brom' and 'Stoke' and replaces them with the corresponding strings ID in another table called 'Teams'.

However it returns nothing! 0 rows added!

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, I just have very little idea what is going on!

Thankyou

Comment: Either `INSERT () VALUES()`, or `INSERT () SELECT`, don't do a `INSERT () VALUES(SELECT)`. (In other words, drop the `VALUES()` surrounding it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from when I was experimenting, I'll edit it out!

Comment: try the `select` alone. does it return any rows?

Comment: What does your `SELECT` return in isolation?

Comment: Select in isolation inserts 1, '11/05/2014' and 12 into 400 rows.

Comment: Is the query running proper or not? Is there some unique key violation happening?

Comment: Nope I don't think so?